# python: sorting two lists of polygons for intersections

Tags: python, sorting, geometry, gis

I have two big lists of polygons.

Using python, I want to take each polygon in list 1, and find the results of its geometric intersection with the polygons in list 2 (I'm using [shapely](http://trac.gispython.org/lab/wiki/Shapely) to do this).

So for polygon *i* in list 1, there may be several polygons in list 2 that would intersect with it.

The problem is that both lists are big, and if I simply nest two loops and run the intersection command for every
possible pair of polygons, it takes a really long time. I'm not sure if preceding the intersection with a boolean test would speed this up significantly (e.g. if intersects: return intersection).

What would be a good way for me to sort or organize these two lists of polygons in order to make the intersections
more efficient? Is there a sorting algorithm that would be appropriate to this situation, and which I could make with python?

I am relatively new to programming, and have no background in discrete mathematics, so if you know an existing algorithm
 that I should use, (which I assume exist for these kinds of situations), please link to or give some explanation that could assist me in actually
implementing it in python.

Also, if there's a better StackExchange site for this question, let me know. I feel like it kind of bridges general python programming, gis, and geometry, so I wasn't really sure.

Comment: Are the polygons convex?

Comment: Their vertices may form convex or concave angles, they also have holes, but I can easily use their bounding boxes if that would help.

Comment: Space partitioning! Quad tree, or volumetric kd-tree on the bounding boxes.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Quadtrees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree) are often used for the purpose of narrowing down the sets of polygons that need to be checked against each other - two polygons only need to be checked against each other if they both occupy at least one of the same regions in the quadtree. How deep you make your quadtree (in the case of polygons, as opposed to points) is up to you.

Comment: Do you think quadtrees are simple enough to implement in this case that I should just read into it and put one together in python? Or is this the kind of thing that I should learn to use an existing library for (such as the QuadTree class in pygame)?

Comment: This sounds like the best answer. Thank you Amber.

Answer (score 3):

Even just dividing your space up to smaller constant-size areas would speed up the intersection detection (if your polygons are small and sparse enough). You make a grid and mark each polygon to belong to some cells in the grid. And then find cells that have more than one polygon in them and make the intersection calculations for those polygons only. This optimization is the easiest to code, but the most ineffective. The second easiest and more effective way would be quadtrees. Then there are BSP tres, KD trees, and BVH trees that are probably the most effective, but the hardest to code.

Edit:
Another optimization would be the following: find out the left-most and the right-most vertices of each polygon and put them in a list. Sort the list and then loop it somehow from left to right and easily find polygons whose bounding boxes' x coordinates overlap, and then make the intersection calculations for those polygons.

Comment: thanks kynnysmatto - it's helpful to hear how the approaches differ.